# Possible to use Applescript or Automator to authenticate iPhone 5s with my Macbook Pro without entering lockcode on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applescript, automator, password, script

Is it possible to utilize Automator/Applescript or similiar on my 2012 MacBook Pro Laptop running 10.13.3 (High Sierra) to automatically pair with my iPhone 5s when I plug it in to my computer. Thereby removing the request to tap in my lockcode on the phone sceen to have my computer recognise my phone?

My phone is currently in 'iPhone is disabled' mode. I do know my passcode, the iPhone jumped straight to iPhone disabled mode after 'hanging' during my last OS update.

I am holding off doing a restore (via iTunes) as I am a believer that there is always a workaround. I just need to find the person who knows the workaround.

I would like to retrieve my recent iphone data (5 months since last back up) before I do a total factory reset (via iTunes) to regain access to my phone.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Is your iPhone running iOS 11?

Comment: Update - iPhone running 10.3.3 ver.

Comment: Did you have the iPhone connected to your Mac before? So was there a trusted connection before? I still think it's not possible. Because in iOS 10 it was the case you needed to trust a computer every time you connected.. It's an interaction that's needed from the iPhone side and has less todo with the Mac side... but maybe someone else has a better answer. I'm also curious now

Comment: Yes, I have previously connected my iPhone to my MBP and trusted. I was wondering if there was an option - on the mac - using Terminal? SystemsPrefs? Library? etc to add a script to validate the serial/iPhone/passcode, so that my computer essentially validates/skips this step on the phone, until I can regain access to my iphone screen. Thanks once again, appreciate your input.

Comment: Additionally - I have a 4s iPhone running 9.3.5 which I am currently using (with my sim) until I can regain access to my 5s. I also have an iPad running 10.3.3 which is linked on same AppleID, iCloud account, iTunes etc and fully accessible via my mac or stand alone.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. iOS 11 requires a pincode or password before allowing a computer access to your iPhone.

> With iOS 11, you are required to enter your device passcode before a
>   connection with a computer is made, even when the phone is unlocked.
>   This is a very nice improvement over the previous "Trust" pop-up.
>
> Now, even if the phone is unlocked with Touch-ID or the new Face-ID,
>   connecting to an unknown computer will still require your 4 or 6 digit
>   pin code, or the alphanumeric password if you have one set up.

[Source](https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/ios-11-a-complete-guide-to-ios-security-and-privacy/)

Comment: Correction. Apologies, just checked legacy iOS website. The iphone is running 10.3.3 ver.